# Eclipse RCP: Unable to export as Eclipse Product: No Repository found containing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I know this technology is quite old but I hope someone is familiar with it.

*Problem:*

I have an eclipse RCP application which is runs perfectly but when I try to export it as ECLIPSE PRODUCT, it fails with the below error:

```
 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.css,1.7.0.v201011041433
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.util,1.7.0.v201011041433
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.util.gui,1.7.0.v200903091627
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit,4.11.0.v201303080030
```

I have the jars present in `$eclipse_installation_directory/plugins` folder, also the reason why the application runs! But I am having a hard time finding why wouldn't it export

Help please!

Comment: Export only looks in the workspace and your target platform, everything must be available in one of those locations.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll try after adding the JARs in the project's build path. Hope that works

Comment: Jars in the build path won't work. These are plug-ins, they must be handled as plug-ins - either listed in the target platform or as plug-in projects in the workspace.

Comment: Yes! You are right. Thank you so much. I was able to export it correctly by adding the plugins. 

Adding the step for someone else who might run into this problem: 

Window -> Preference -> Plug-In development -> Target directory (pointed towards the directory that contained my jars)